# Passing string parameter to user created jQuery function

Tags: jquery

Via the `onClick` method of an a `href` tag I'm trying to pass three variables, two numbers and a string, to jQuery method I've created. The numbers are passed with no problem at all, but with respect to passing the string variable with `answer_text = TEST TEST`, I'm getting the error below. I think I'm encoding the string incorrectly. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Firefox 15, Firebug, and Twitter bootstrap.

> SyntaxError: missing } after property list

```
$().edit_answer({
  row: 0, 
  num_answer: 0, 
  answer_text: TEST TEST
});

onClick="$().edit_answer({
  row:' + row_id + ', 
  num_answer:' + num_ans + ',
  answer_text:\"' + ans +'\"
});"
```

The reason for all the quotes is the full a `href` tag is being generated dynamically

```
jQuery.fn.edit_answer = function () {
    var args = arguments[0] || {};
    var row = args.row;
    var num_answer  =  args.num_answer;
    var answer_text = args.answer_text;
};
```

Comment: Ew, inline JS and jQuery? I'd look in to use `data-*` attributes and put everything in the jquery `.click()`. Also, I feel like this is code found in the middle of a `document.write` (with regards to the onclick code)--is that accurate?

Answer (score 0):

```
onClick="$().edit_answer({row:' + row_id + ', num_answer:' + num_ans + ',answer_text:\"' + ans +'\"});"
```

quote ? row:'

'row:' + row_id + ', num_answer:' + num_ans + ',answer_text:"' + ans +'"'

try that line.

Comment: Many thanks for the assistance I ended up with this abomination working just fine: \'row\':\'' + row_id + '\', \'num_answer\':\'' + num_ans + '\', \'answer_text\':\'' + ans +'\'